# Change element text without jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the contents of a div without using jQuery. I want to select the div by id or class.

Ive managed to get append to work:

```
function appendHtml(targetC, htmldata) {
    var theDiv = document.getElementById(targetC);
    var newNode = document.createElement('div');
    newNode.innerHTML = htmldata;
    theDiv.appendChild(newNode) 
}
```

But cant figure out how to change text of one..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sv4CP/) fiddle for a basic sample

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function bold(targetC) {
        var theDiv = document.getElementById(targetC);
        theDiv.innerHTML = '<b>' + theDiv.innerHTML + '</b>';
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload='bold("message")'>
   <div>Hello, World!</div>
   <div id="message">What a nice day!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

```
<div id="foo">old text</div>
```

The JS code:

```
function appendHtml(targetC, htmldata) {
    var theDiv = document.getElementById(targetC);
    theDiv.innerHTML = htmldata;
}

appendHtml('foo', 'new text');
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7QjcB/

Comment: @Alosyius Give it an id, look for it and use `innerHTML` to change it.

Comment: @Alosyius Sorry, changed my answer. Not sure if it worked, but IE7 has started to age.

Answer (score 0):

simply change the html of a div by using `innerHTML`

```
var anyDiv = document.getElementById(targetID);

html = "content";
anydiv.innerHTML(html);
```

as a variation of your provided function:

```
function changeHtml(targetC, htmldata) {
    var theDiv = document.getElementById(targetC);
    theDIV.innerHTML = htmldata;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wS3SF/) that might answer your question. All I changed was getting the element before and then passing it in.

```
function appendHtml(targetC, htmldata) {
var newNode = document.createElement('div');
newNode.innerHTML = htmldata;
targetC.appendChild(newNode);
}

var getDiv = document.getElementById("testing");
```