# How do I write something with javascript in an HTML webpage without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am beginning to program. In the bottom code, when run, will completely refresh the page. How can I avoid this? Thank you very much for your time!

```html
<h1>Space Calculator Demo</h1><br> If you were to start a trip at
<script type="text/javascript">
  function printTime() {
    var d = new Date();
    var hours = d.getHours();
    var mins = d.getMinutes();
    var secs = d.getSeconds();
    document.body.innerHTML = hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
  }
  setInterval(printTime, 1000);
</script>
<div id="time"></div> , how long would it take you and how much food and water would you need?
```

Comment: It does not refresh the page, but you set the html of the whole body `document.body.innerHTML` to the text.

Comment: It doesn't refresh you page, it just overrides the complete html. The selector for `document.body.innerHTML` just has to be: `document.getElementById('time').innerHTML`, **[example](https://jsfiddle.net/ak3zwak7/)**

Comment: or [how to change text value within an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15296589/change-element-text-without-jquery), [Replace only text inside a div using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867269/replace-only-text-inside-a-div-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

The page isn't refreshing, you were setting the entire body of the page equal to your time. Instead of setting `body`, set `time`.

```html
<h1>Space Calculator Demo</h1><br> If you were to start a trip at
<script type="text/javascript">
  function printTime() {
    var d = new Date();
    var hours = d.getHours();
    var mins = d.getMinutes();
    var secs = d.getSeconds();
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs + ",";
  }
  setInterval(printTime, 1000);
</script>
<div id="time"></div>How long would it take you and how much food and water would you need?
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of rewriting the body, use document.getElementById('time') and set the text of that element only

Answer (score 1):

By assigning to `document.body.innerHTML`, you are overwriting all content on the page. `document.body` refers to the entire page, so setting is HTML erases everything that was there before (your header, div, and text).

It looks like what you want to do is only change the contents of `<div id="time"></div>`. For that, you should change the line

```
document.body.innerHTML = hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
```

to this:

```
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = hours + ":" + mins + ":" + secs;
```

This will overwrite only the contents of your `div`, leaving the rest of the page intact.